# Overriding a composer repository with bitbucket

Tags: composer-php

Trying to override a repository in composer.json with a bitbucket repository but having no luck at all. I've looked at `composer show repo` and dumped the output with the `-vvv` verbose setting but there doesn't seem to be any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong.
Am I missing something?

```
// composer.json
{
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://bitbucket.org/dominicwatson/dlutwbootstrap-active"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "dlu/dlutwbootstrap": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

And after doing `show` I can see that it's picking it up correctly

```
// php composer.phar show dlu/dlutwbootstrap
name     : dlu/dlutwbootstrap                                 
descrip. : ZF2 module to generate Twitter Bootstrap UI - forms, navigation, etc.
keywords : dlutwbootstrap, twitter bootstrap, zf2, zend framework 2, module
versions : * dev-master, 0.1.4, 0.1.3, 0.1.2, 0.1.1
type     : library
license  : New-BSD-License
source   : [git] https://bitbucket.org/dominicwatson/dlutwbootstrap-active bf81affa8f72e29a8cd6ecd3126ab0ab4cbb43d4
dist     : []  
names    : dlu/dlutwbootstrap

autoload
psr-0
DluTwBootstrap => src/
classmap
./Module.php

requires
zendframework/zendframework dev-master
```

When I do `php composer.phar -vvv update` I see it looking through my override repository, but at the end, it just decides to get the original instead.

Should get: `bf81affa8f72e29a8cd6ecd3126ab0ab4cbb43d4`

Actually gets: `843d123dbb8e2eba65d4ef58f7cdaf7f59b0d51d`

Comment: with bitbucket i usually use "default" instead of "dev-master"

Comment: I thought dev-master basically meant "master" branch, which is all good, working etc. Not sure what default does. I managed to get it working by pushing the tag "0.2". For some reason, it now pulls that as I guess it sees it as the latest version?